# stringwithformat gives memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have written code as given below

```
strPageText=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",strPageText,data];
```

This is in loop. it gives me a memory leak error.

Comment: This line itself does not contain memory leak.The problem must be in some other code.

Comment: strPageText is static variable.This line gives me memory leak at 3 different places

Comment: Show your code where you declare and initialize  strPageText. You should probably use NSMutableString appendString instead.

Answer (score 2):

Like Vladimir said the code does not have a memory leak.

But you are using factory method stringWithFormat to create your string. So the object is autoreleased. And if you are running this in a loop, you must be getting a lot of autoreleased objects. So for better memory management your code should handle allocating and releasing the memory of your objects:

```
    strPageText=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",strPageText,data];
```

and the release the string at the end of the loop before next iteration.

```
    [strPageText release];
```

Comment: This won't work. strPageText is already initialized at this point.

Comment: this increases the memory leak. becuse its in loop